# JavaScript script doesn't work in Tomcat but works in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a Java EE web application using JSP pages. I included some JavaScript in JSP but it doesn't work when I run it on the server. It does work on Chrome.

Any ideas?

Here's my JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
<head>
  <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){ //Add, Save, Edit and Delete functions code 
    //$(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit); 
    //$(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete); 
    $("#btnAddd").bind("click", Add); 
    $('#btnSave1').click(function(event) {       
        var engagement_code = "a" ;//$('#code').val();
        var engagement_name = "b";//$('#name').val();
        //var harga = $('#harga').val();
        var json = { "engagement_code" : engagement_code, "engagement_name" : engagement_name};
        $.ajax({
            url: 'engagementregister',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'engagement_code': engagement_code,
                'engagement_name': engagement_name,

            }),
            processData: false,
            ContentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function () {
                console.log("success");}

    });
    });
});
    //$("#btnSave1").bind("click", Save1);

function Add()
{ $("#list tbody").append(
        "<tr>"+ 
        "<td><img src='image/edit.png'/></td>"+
        "<td><input id='code' type='text'/></td>"+ 
        "<td><input id='name' type='text'/></td>"+ 
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+ 
        "<td><select id='sl'> <option value='ADM' label='ADM'/><option value='CSD' label='CSD'/><option value='PBS' label='PBS'/></select></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        //"<td><img src='image/edit.png' class='btnSave'></td>"+  
        "<td><input type='button' value='Save' onclick='Save()' class='btnSave'/></td>" +"</tr>");
        $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);  
        //$(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit); 
        }; 

function Save()
{ 
var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr 
var tdCode = par.children("td:nth-child(2)"); 
var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(3)"); 
var tdClient = par.children("td:nth-child(4)"); 
var tdSL = par.children("td:nth-child(5)");
var tdBU = par.children("td:nth-child(6)");
var tdEM = par.children("td:nth-child(7)");
var tdButton1 = par.children("td:nth-child(1)"); 
var tdButton2 = par.children("td:nth-child(8)"); 
//var e = document.getElementById("sl");
//var tdSL = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
tdCode.html(tdCode.children("input[type=text]").val()); 
tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val()); 
tdClient.html(tdClient.children("input[type=text]").val()); 
tdSL.html(tdSL.children('select').val());
tdBU.html(tdBU.children("input[type=text]").val()); 
tdEM.html(tdEM.children("input[type=text]").val());
tdButton1.html("<img src='image/edit.png' class='btnEdit'/>");

//$(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit); 
};
</script>
<title>Engagement list</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Engagement list</h1>

<c:url var="editImgUrl" value="edit.png" />
<c:url var="deleteImgUrl" value="delete.png" />
<c:if test="${!empty list}">
<form>
<div style="overflow:scroll;overflow:auto">

    <table id="list" style="border: 1px solid; width: 100%; text-align:center">
        <thead style="background:#d3dce3">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="1"></th>

                <th>Engagement code</th>
                <th>Engagement Name</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>SL</th>
                <th>BU</th>
                <th>EM</th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody style="background:#ccc">
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="eng">

            <c:url var="detailsUrl" value="/details?id=${eng.engagement_code}" />

            <tr>
            <td><a href="details?id=${eng.engagement_code}"><img src="${deleteImgUrl}"></img></a></td> 
                <td>${eng.engagement_code}</td>
                <td><c:out value="${eng.engagement_name}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${eng.client}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${eng.SL}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${eng.BU}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${eng.EM}" /></td>

   <td><a href="eneditform?id=${eng.engagement_code}"><img src="${editImgUrl}"></img></a></td>  


   </tr>

 </c:forEach>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${empty list}">  
No records found.

</c:if>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<button id="btnAddd">New</button>
<button id="btnSave1">Save</button>
<%-- <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="Save1()"/>--%>
 <a href="accueil">return</a>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is extremely rare that anyone here can answer a question about why some code doesn't work without seeing the actual code pasted into your question.  Also, it is unclear what "Javascript in jsp running on the server" even means.

Comment: doesn't make sense comparing server to browser

Comment: i didn't put code because it works fine when i access to app from Chrome via http://localhost//appname/..... But when i run the app from eclipse and run it on server, it works fine but the javascript part is not. I edited my question

Comment: What's the difference between "works" and "doesn't work"? Does the page body get rendered correctly from JSP template? What does Chrome's JS console tell you?

Comment: @kryger ok i'll explain what this page is supposed to show. I have a table with data retrieved from database, and i have a button "add" that allows me to add a row in the table with text fields and save it javascript and jquery. this works fine in chrome, but in eclipse, the page is rendered with the table but i can 't add the row but there is no error in console

Comment: @maryam what do you mean by **eclipse** ?! are you trying to see your page with eclipse internal browser ?

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi yes eclipse internal browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eclipse internal browser is not a complete browser and it does not support all modern browsers features (JS, CSS ...)

You can start tomcat in eclipse and use other browser.

Comment: finally that's what i did. Thank you all for your interest